# Build failure with Android's sample TicTacToe (from command line)

Tags: android, command-line, jar, tic-tac-toe

I've been trying to build the TicTacToeLib & TicTacToeMain from the command line. Since I didn't see an Android.mk for each of these projects, I created my own, but having trouble when importing the packages. Here is what I have for TicTacToeLib:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TicTacToeLib
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
#LOCAL_MODULE := TicTacToeLib
#LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
#include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

Tried building a JAVA library (assuming I could import from the built .jar), but had errors with R.stamp related resources. So, I reverted to building a package which creates the apk. Here is what I have for TicTacToeMain:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TicTacToeMain
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

The error I see is:

> target Java: TicTacToeMain (out/target/common/obj/APPS/TicTacToeMain_intermediates/classes)
>       external/TicTacToeMain/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity.java:25: package com.example.android.tictactoe.library does not exist
>       import com.example.android.tictactoe.library.GameActivity;
>                                               ^
>       external/TicTacToeMain/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity.java:26: package     com.example.android.tictactoe.library.GameView does not exist
>       import com.example.android.tictactoe.library.GameView.State;
>                                                        ^
>       external/TicTacToeMain/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity.java:51: cannot find symbol
>       symbol  : class GameActivity
>       location: class com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity
>           Intent i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
>                                       ^
>       external/TicTacToeMain/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity.java:52: cannot find symbol
>       symbol  : variable GameActivity
>       location: class com.example.android.tictactoe.MainActivity
>           i.putExtra(GameActivity.EXTRA_START_PLAYER,
>                      ^
>        external/TicTacToeMain/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity.java:53: package State does not exist
>                   startWithHuman ? State.PLAYER1.getValue() : State.PLAYER2.getValue());
>                                         ^
>       external/TicTacToeMain/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/MainActivity.java:53: package State does not exist
>                   startWithHuman ? State.PLAYER1.getValue() : State.PLAYER2.getValue());
>                                                                    ^
>       6 errors
>       make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/TicTacToeMain_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41

Finally, I commented out all the R.string.* usages and built a JAVA library (.jar is created) as well but TicTacToeMain still fails with the same build errors. Would truly appreciate any help